# Can i get direct folders that are under a parent folder using Get-PnPFolderItem

Tags: powershell

I have a SharePoint online document library which contain the following:-

1. Site url = /sites/Clients/
2. Document library = Customer Share
3. Main Folder name = Clients

now i want to get all the Direct folders that are under the Clients main folder, is this possible.

I have this PnP Power shell, but this will list everything inside the document library

```
$SiteURL = "https://*********.sharepoint.com/sites/Clients"
$mainfolderUrl = "/sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clients"
$listName = "Customer Share"



Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
##$customerFolders = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $mainfolderUrl -PageSize 1  -ScriptBlock {}

$customerFolders= Get-PnPListItem -List $listName -FolderServerRelativeUrl $mainfolderUrl -PageSize 1  -ScriptBlock {} | Select-Object id,@{label="Filename";expression={$_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef}},@{label="Fileurl";expression={$_.FieldValues.FileRef}}


    ForEach($customerFolder in $customerFolders)
    {
      $customerFolder
    }


Id Filename                                      Fileurl
-- --------                                      -------
 4 ClientA                                       /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientA
 5 ClientB                                       /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientB
 6 ClientC                                       /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientC
13 underB                                        /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientB/underB
15 underb2                                       /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientB/underB/underb2
19 em                                            /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientC/em
 7 Questions-Database Programmer V1.docx         /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientA/Questio…
 8 Sharepoint-metabata-sitesV3.docx              /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientA/Sharepoint-meta…
 9 Sharepoint-metabata-sites.docx                /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientA/Sharepoint-meta…
10 Questions-Database Programmer.docx            /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientA/Questio…
11 1212 - Copy.xlsx                              /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientB/1212 - Copy.xlsx
12 1212 - Copy - Copy.xlsx                       /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientB/1212 - Copy - C…
14 guru_card_export.csv                          /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientB/underB/guru_car…
16 SharePoint-quote.xlsx                         /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientB/underB/underb2/…
17 Pic-4.png                                     /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientC/Pic-4.png
18 Pic-3.png                                     /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientC/Pic-3.png
20 paras script.txt                              /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientB/paras script.txt
21 guru_card_export (1).csv                      /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientB/underB/underb2/…
22 contracts.png                                 /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientB/underB/contract…
23 General IO.xlsx                               /sites/Clients/Customer Share/Clientss/ClientB/General…
```

now after getting the direct folders under the "Clients" main folder, i want to loop through the content of each of the sub-folders separatly .. can anyone advice?
any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Get-PnPFolderItem` instead of using `Get-PnPListItem`.

**Example**:

```
Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl "CustomerShare/Clients" -ItemType Folder
```

**Folder content**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: based on my testing using `-FolderSiteRelativeUrl` will raise threshold error when we query a list which have more than 5000 items even if we use -Page Size